# VSCode escaping semicolons in task arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyinstaller, vscode-tasks

I am trying to create a task to run PyInstaller.

One of the command arguments requires the format `[--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>]`. on windows `;` is required - cant use `:`

I am having difficulty escaping the semicolon in the task definition

I have tried the value/quoting formats available but none work to escape the semicolon

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Run Pyinstaller",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "powershell",
        "args": [
            "pyinstaller",
            "--onefile",
            "--noconsole",
            "--name=my_app",
            "--icon=release/shrt_icon.ico",
            "--log-level=WARN",
            "--add-data",
            {
                "value": "release/my_data.dat;.",
                "quoting": "weak"
            },
            "cli.py"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ]
    }
]
```

Desired command

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --name=my_app --icon=release/shrt_icon.ico --log-level=WARN --add-data "release/my_data.dat;." cli.py`

Output from task
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution to this issue

The backtick to escape the semicolon doesn't seem to work when breaking apart the command into args as above, but it does work when including as a single line command with the `-Command` argument

```
        "args": [
            "-Command",
            "pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --name=myapp --icon=release/mydata.dat --log-level=WARN --add-data \"release/mydata.dat`;.\" cli.py"
        ],
```